# How to resolve 'Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException' error in Laravel while using Socialite package in a local environment?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, laravel-socialite

Despite having installed the Socialite package in my local Laravel application, configured the **`app.php`** and **`services`** files with the same redirect URL, I still encounter the 'Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException' error when attempting to log in with Google.

I tried some of Stack overflow's answers  and it didn't work!!

Comment: Focus on showing a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example the error comes from your laravel.log, so show the error with its entire stacktrace